# How to make an azure cost management export run daily and only export that day or previous days data? Using terraform or azure api

Tags: azure, terraform, cost-management

Taking the Terraform resource example:

```
resource "azurerm_billing_account_cost_management_export" "example" {
  name                         = "example"
  billing_account_id           = "example"
  recurrence_type              = "Daily"
  recurrence_period_start_date = "2020-08-18T00:00:00Z"
  recurrence_period_end_date   = "2020-09-18T00:00:00Z"

  export_data_storage_location {
    container_id     = azurerm_storage_container.example.resource_manager_id
    root_folder_path = "/root/updated"
  }

  export_data_options {
    type       = "Usage"
    time_frame = "Custom"
  }
}
```

The documentation isn't very clear what time_frame = "Custom" does and what else to add here?, I would like to create an export that runs daily however it only exports that day or maybe the previous days worth of data not month-to-date being the closest to this. As i do not want all of the other days data on that export. Is Setting the time_frame to custom allow me to do this? Will i have to set a start_date and end_date? and if so can i then run an update request daily potentially to change the days in a script someway as an alternative option

Tried creating a day-to-month export however the file is too large and comes with unwanted data as the end of the month comes along

Answer (score 1):

Is Setting the time_frame to custom allow me to do this?

Yes, we can do this via [json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/exports/get?source=recommendations&tabs=HTTP) api.
[image]

Terraform provider it self not supporting this option. Refer below screenshots.

I have replicated the ways using terraform, no luck. **Using terraform we have only below custom options.**  time_frame only allows below mentioned parameters.
[image]

**Possible values include:  `WeekToDate`,  `MonthToDate`,  `BillingMonthToDate`,  `TheLastWeek`,  `TheLastMonth`,  `TheLastBillingMonth`,  `Custom`.**

**seems the respective custom parameters are specific to Month.**
we can use like

```
time_frame  =  "TheLastMonth"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the  [Azure Cost Management connector in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-azure-cost-management) , upload that on Power BI and set a daily refresh.

You can then query the Datamart like a database daily.